# Ajax Toolkit CascadingDropDown onload event?

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, toolkit

I would like to know if this is possible to create an JavaScript/jQuery event on Ajax Toolkit CascadingDropDon load.

Scenario:

I am selecting item on first dropdown -> second dropdown is loaded with Ajax Toolkit cascading dropdown feature -> as a reaction for this my JavaScript function fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it!

Here's a method:

In CascadinDropDown declaration I have added BehaviourID:

```
<cc1:CascadingDropDown 
ID="CascadingDDL" 
TargetControlID="childDDL" 
ParentControlID="parentDDL"
Category="ddl"
PromptText="Select"
ServicePath="~/webmethods.asmx"  
runat="server" **BehaviorID="cddBehaviourID"**
ServiceMethod="GetValuesForDDL" Enabled="True">
</cc1:CascadingDropDown>
```

In script:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {    //For Ajax toolkit to fire on 'window.onload'

      var behavior = $find('<%=CascadingDDL.BehaviurID %>');

      if (behavior != null) {

            behavior.add_populated(function() { *what you want to execute* });

      }
}
```

Comment: Man, so glad I found this.  Needed, under certain circumstances, to add an option item to a dropdownlist that is controlled by a CascadingDrowpDown.  Could not figure that out until I read this post.