# Asp.NET Webforms CascadingDropdown Databind Timing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, cascadingdropdown

CascadingDropdown using a webmethod to retrieve items from a db that populate the parent dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAssignDept" runat="server"/>
                        <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cddAssignDept" runat="server" 
                            TargetControlID="ddlAssignDept" Category="Department" 
                            PromptText="Select a Department" ServicePath="~/services/srv_Cascading.asmx" 
                            ServiceMethod="GetDepartment" Enabled="True" />
```

My Problem:  At run time, under certain circumstances, I need to add a new list item to this dropdown.  I cannot find where in the page life cycle to do this.

My question is:  At what time in the page life cycle does the binding occur.  From my testing, it appears to be one of the very last events.
How can I add a list item at run time to the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another StackOverflow post

[Ajax Toolkit CascadingDropDown onload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883263/ajax-toolkit-cascadingdropdown-onload-event)

The key is adding a handler for the cascading dropdown's add_populated event.